# Microsoft ClickToRun folder - reduce size

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office-2016

I get every few days a new sub-folder  in microsoft ClickToRun folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\ClickToRun`.  I have the office 2016 preview which is installed using this technology. each sub folder has hundreds of files like this one:

```
A796A3A0-C534-4C16-B12A-5B95B6F05D8B.stream.x64.x-none.1028069089
```

It's now about 11 GB of my hard drive.
Can I erase the old ones? why is it growing so big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was uninstall Office, delete the ClickToRun folder, then used the Office Deployment Tool to download and install Office.

http://www.askvg.com/tip-customize-microsoft-office-click-to-run-c2r-setup-to-install-selected-programs-only/

I now have Office installed again and my ClickToRun folder is just 12mb.

Comment: I already did that as a solution for the problem, but I rather find a solution that doesn't require uninstalling and re-installing office every 3 months......